# ggplot2: How to place plot legend below caption

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to place the plot legend below my plot **AND** my caption. While I'm able to change most stylistic aspects of the caption - for instance, using `plot.caption` - I haven't found a way to change the positioning of the caption.

Here's what I have so far:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species)) + 
      + geom_point(size=6) + labs(caption = "Note: Dots are closer than they appear") + 
      theme_minimal() + theme(legend.position = c("bottom"))
```

Is there a way to do this or some work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try using `lemon::reposition_legend`.

https://github.com/stefanedwards/lemon

And you can reposition the caption over the legend:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point(size =6) +
  labs(caption = "Note: Dots are closer than they appear") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = c("bottom"),
        plot.caption.position = "plot",
        plot.caption = element_text(vjust = 40))
```

Comment: `lemon::reposition_legend` works well when I want to place the legend within the plot but I don't see how it helps me move things outside of the plot. Looking at my example I want the items below the x-axis to be in the following order: x-axis label, caption, legend.